# Machine learning in Bot

Tags: botframework

I have build a bot to perform some actions. The bot ask  series of questions for completing the required action. Is there a way in which, I can add machine learning in my bot. So that it learns the pattern of answer a particular user give. And next time less questions from user.

How can we add machine learning in Microsoft bot?

Comment: Machine learning does best with lots and lots of data.  I don't see how your series of questions qualifies.

Comment: Look for AIML if your goal is to create a chatbot.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use simple statistics :

1) Save each user path on an array

Ex:

```
user1 = [1, 3, 3, 4, 1]
user2 = [2, 3, 3, 4, 2]
user3 = [1, 3, 3, 4, 4]
user4 = [1, 3, 3, 3, 1]
user5 = [4, 2, 3, 3, 1]
```

2) User a cron that match patterns, here you'll see that when answer 1 is choosen, most of the user then pick answer 3 and answer 3 again.

3) Save that pattern somewhere and each time your app is used, check these patterns

I believe simple solution like that are better than recreating an IA ...

Good luck !